# Recursive Runtime of Tree Recovery Program

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, runtime, analysis

I am trying to figure out the runtime of a recursive algorithm that I have come up with. The algorithm, given a preOrder and inOrder traversal of a tree, finds the postOrder traversal. Here is my algorithm:

```
Recovery(preOrder, inOrder):
  root = preOrder[0]
  rootIndex = inOrder.find(root)

  if preOrder.length <= 0
      return;

  leftPreord = preOrder[1...rootIndex]
  leftInord = inOrder[0...rootIndex]
  rightPreord = preOrder[rootIndex + 1 ... End]
  rightInord = inOrder[rootIndex + 1 ... End]

  Recovery(leftPreord, leftInord)
  Recovery(rightPreord, rightInord)

  print preOrder[0]
```

My question is if this algorithm basically has the same run time as the MergeSort algorithm, O(nlogn).

The non recursive part of the algorithm (mainly the .find() operator) runs in O(n) time, then the two recursive calls run in T(n/2) time. Therefore, T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n). The height of the tree is log n and each level runs in n time, hence O(nlogn). My only concern is that for each recursive call it is technically T((n-1)/2) because we leave the current root behind. Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is sound.  The steps of each iteration consist of the sum of O(1) and O(n) operations.  The sum of these is simply the highest order of any of the steps: O(n).  You have log(n) [base2] levels, which does, indeed, leave you with an algorithm of O(n log n).

Good reasoning.